# How to join lines in QGIS for later using "lines to poly"?

Tags: qgis, line, merge, polyline-creation, geometry-conversion

After successfully merging lines (using snapping) with merge_selected_features i got nice result - one merged line. Next thing was to make polygon from created merged line. Result is not nice - it creates multiple polygons connecting ends from separate lines which were merged previously together. Somehow merging geometry is not working for me or i am missing something.

..
Solved. I imported lines in Grass, then i used v.build.polylines and got nice line from which i was able to create correct polygon.

Comment: Instead of editing the title to include "Solved", please accept an answer. If there is no suitable answer, you can write one yourself.

Comment: got it. just didnt want to wait 8 hours ;)

Comment: It should have worked. I have tested it in QGIS 1.8 in windows vista, and the merge_features --> Lines to Polygons sequence worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I should try using the Polygoniser plug-in. You shouldn't need to merge the lines to use this. See: http://confound.me.uk/maps/ppv4.pdf

Nick.

Comment: Testing right now. New version went to 55% and old version - to 95%; both didnt work, it freezed and stopped QGIS.

Comment: Pleased to hear that you've got around the problem. For the record, to work the polygonizer plug-in needs the python-shapely package to be installed. N.

Comment: will try with OSGeo4W. previously tried with installed QGIS version and i guess without that shapely lib.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a result of the lines being different directions? I believe it should work if all the joined lines are in the same direction & then reindexed so that the node numbers are in the proper sequence.