# Converting Lines to Polygons in QGIS produces Sliver Polygons

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, polygonize

While trying to polygonize the polyline layer in PyQGIS using

```py
processing.runandload("qgis:linestopolygons",explode_path,polygon_path)
```

command in  python console, it does not create polygons corresponding to the line edges. Instead it creates sliver polygons along the curved edges. Why the polygons are not created along the line edges?

[image]

On polygonization, the black lines are supposed to be the edges of the created polygons. Instead only few slivers are created along the curved edges(blue polygons).

Comment: Have you tried the SAGA version of the tool: `processing.runandload("saga:convertlinestopolygons",explode_path,polygon_path)`

Comment: @Joseph tried the SAGA version just now. Still the result is same.

Comment: Try cleaning your line shapefile with the plugin **Geometry Checker** or the GRASS tool **v.clean**.

Comment: @Joseph the data is topologically clean. Got the desired result using 'Polygonize' tool. Thank you for the comments. Have come to know about couple of topological checkers :)

Comment: Nice one, glad you found the solution =)

Comment: The problem here is before polygonize it is necessary to recognize rings, instead these tools only create polygons using start node and end node of the same linestring. Take in account the desired polygons are composed of multiple linestring segments that must be grouped in rings before polygonize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got the exact polygons as desired using the 'Polygonize' algorithm (Processing Toolbox --> QGIS Geoalgorithms --> Polygonize) in the python console.

```
import processing
polygon_path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\polygonsFormed.shp"
line_path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\inputLine.shp"
processing.runandload("qgis:polygonize",line_path,False,False,polygon_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while using the 'Lines to Polygons' tool available in Vector menu. Got lot of little sliver polygons even though the data is topologically correct.

> "Polygonize"

QGIS geoalgorithm available in the processing toolbar worked for me.